# CSS/JQuery: nav Icon change on click

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, nav, buttonclick

I have a nav bar on my page at www.ssangar.com and as you'll be able to see, on hover the icon changes to white and a text label rolls out. 
The page is a single page layout website, so uses anchor points, but I am trying to make it so that when the user clicks on the nav bar or scrolls to next section, that icon stays highlighted. I currently have this jquery code, my knowledge isn't very advanced but right now on click, the background image changes to the white icon.

Javascript:

```
$('.nav a').click(function(e){
var elem = $(this).find('li')
var className = elem.attr('class');
var iconName = className.substring(0, className.length - 4);
elem.css('background-image', 'url("Icons/' + iconName + '_hl.png")');
});
```

And CSS:

```
    .navtext,
.visuallyhidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-240px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-240px);
    transform: translateX(-240px);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s;
    transition: transform 0.2s;
    z-index:-1;
}

.nav a:hover .navtext {
    clip: auto;
    height: 30px;
    width: 90px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: .25em .25em;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(40, 40, 40, .7);;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: visible;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(30%);
    transform: translateX(30%);
}

.nav ul li {
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:75%;
    background-position:center; 
    line-height:30px;
}

.nav li.home_ico{
    background-image: url('Icons/home.png');
}

.nav li.home_ico:hover{
    background-image: url('Icons/home_hl.png');
}
.nav li.about_ico{
    background-image: url('Icons/about.png');
}

.nav li.about_ico:hover{
    background-image: url('Icons/about_hl.png');
}
.nav li.about_ico:active{
    background-image: url('Icons/about_hl.png');
}

.nav  li.team_ico{
    background-image: url('Icons/team.png');
}

.nav  li.team_ico:hover{
    background-image: url('Icons/team_hl.png');
}

.nav  li.process_ico{
    background-image: url('Icons/process.png');
}

.nav  li.process_ico:hover{
    background-image: url('Icons/process_hl.png');
}

.nav  li.progress_ico{
    background-image: url('Icons/progress.png');
}

.nav  li.progress_ico:hover{
    background-image: url('Icons/progress+hl.png');
}

.nav li.extras_ico{
    background-image: url('Icons/extras.png');
}

.nav li.extras_ico:hover{
    background-image: url('Icons/extras_hl.png');
}

.nav li.sponsorus_ico{
    background-image: url('Icons/sponsorus.png');
}

.nav li.sponsorus_ico:hover{
    background-image: url('Icons/sponsorus_hl.png');
}

.nav li.sponsors_ico{
    background-image: url('Icons/sponsors.png');
}

.nav li.sponsors_ico:hover{
    background-image: url('Icons/sponsors_hl.png');
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot put a li in a element.

Comment: Have a look @ [automatically_highlight_current_page_in](http://www.richnetapps.com/automatically_highlight_current_page_in/)